# InBuilt Beacon receiver in android or ios

Tags: ibeacon, ibeacon-android, android-ibeacon

I have iBeacon devices to broadcast my shop offers.

I don't want to create new Mobile app to receive my notifications instead i have plan to use in-built beacon receiver to receive my messages.

Please advice me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to create a custom mobile app that will deliver shop offers, your options are limited.  There is are very few apps either installed by default on mobile devices or commonly installed by end users.

Perhaps **the closest option that exists is the Chrome web browser app for iOS.**  In July, Google updated this app to be able to detect Eddystone-URL beacons, which transmit a short URL.  A shop owner can deploy a beacon transmitting a URL to a web page with marketing offers.  The Chrome app then displays this to the user when they pass by.

There are serious limitations to this, the most important of which is that relatively few iOS users have the Chrome browser installed.  You can read more in my blog post on the topic here:

http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2015/07/22/how-to-push-messages-without-an-app.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to have **some** app to do something like this, for a couple of different reasons:

- iBeacons are identified by a unique ID, and apps can monitor for this ID. There's no way to tell iOS to just monitor for every beacon, everywhere. Some app has to tell it to watch for iBeacons with your ID.
- iBeacons do not transmit messages, they only announce their presence. For a message to appear on a user's phone, the message must be presented by an app on the phone. The beacon cannot transmit this information.

There might be a generic app you could glom onto (like @davidgyoung's mention of Chrome). But you can't present messages to users via iBeacon unless they have some app that's going to listen for your beacon and present your message.

Comment: Thanks you tom, i will look into create own app to receive messages.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at the Wallet app (Passbook) on iOS. I haven't looked recently (iOS 8+) but it used to be able to trigger passes based on proximity to beacons. It's installed on iOS and can't be uninstalled. There are Android apps that do something similar but nothing pre-installed that I remember. Depending on your audience/use case, Apple Wallet might work for you (you can do some pretty advanced things with passes).